# Error when building a MySQL table via Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I keep getting an error that my MySQL `CREATE TABLE` statement is incorrect. The code that I have tried is as follows:

```
String tablename = c + d;
String ab = "";

for(int i=1 ; i <= k ; i++)
{
    ab = "column" + k + " VARCHAR(255),";
}
String sql = "CREATE TABLE  "  + tablename + "(id INTEGER not NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT, "  + ab + " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";
```

Any feedback and recommendations greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: You should decide whether you are using MySQL or SQL Server and tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

For MySql, couple of things:

Change your code to:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
     ab += "column" + i + " VARCHAR(255),";
        ^^            ^^^
      append    different column name
 }
 String sql = "CREATE TABLE  " + tablename + "(id INT not NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT, " + ab + " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";
                                                  ^^^
                                           Use INT instead of INTEGER
```